# Local Storage in chrome apps using Dart

Tags: local-storage, dart, google-chrome-app

When I try to use the [Storage](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Storage.html) class in a chrome packaged app like this `window.localStorage` it returns `null`. The code below works fine when launching in Dartium or Chrome though. Why does localstorage not work in Package apps? And what would I write to get the following functionality?

```dart
import 'dart:json';

void save(List data) {
  var jsonString = stringify(data);
  window.localStorage['highscore'] = jsonString;
}

List load() {
  var jsonString = window.localStorage['highscore'];
  return parse(jsonString);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [chrome packaged app API documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage.html), you can't use `window.localStorage` but you can use `chrome.storage` to get an API with similar features (and more).

You also need to request the storage permission in your manifest:

```
...
"permissions": [
    "storage"
],
```

Take a look at [the `chrome` pub package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/chrome) which should provide access to chrome.* APIs in Dart (when you import it in your pubspec.   You're particularly interested in [the `chrome.storage` Dart library](https://github.com/dart-gde/chrome.dart/blob/master/lib/src/storage.dart).

Example of use below (by using the Chrome Packaged App option in the Dart Editor New Application)...:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;
import 'package:chrome/chrome.dart' as chrome;


void main() {
  print("Starting...");
  query("button").onClick.listen(onClick);
}


onClick(e) {
  document.body.append(new Element.html("<p>Clicked...</p>"));
  // save the highscore 123
  chrome.storage.local.set({'highscore':'123'}).then((storageArea) {

    // load the highscore
    chrome.storage.local.get(['highscore']).then((Map<String,String> vals) {
      var highscore = vals['highscore'];
      document.body.append(new Element.html("<p>$highscore</p>"));
    });

  });
}
```

with HTML that looks like this:

```html
...snip
<button>Click Me</button>
<script src="storage.dart" type="application/dart"></script>

<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
<script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>
<script src="packages/js/dart_interop.js"></script>
...
```

and a manifest that looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "StorageExample",
  "version": "1",

  "manifest_version": 2,

  "icons": {"128": "dart_icon.png"},

  "permissions" : [
    "storage"
  ],

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

I havn't tested it in Dartium, but converting to JS and loading as a packaged app into Chrome v28 works fine.

Comment: Ah! Do you know why localstorage is not supported? Also, I get confused by the examples for the chrome storage API using dart. Would you mind posting an implementation of the save and load functions?

Comment: Example code added.  Make sure you add the `chrome` package to your `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: @ChrisBuckett Did you have the chance to try the code in Dartium? For some reasons I can't get, the chrome.local.set method returns without putting anything in the local storage.

Comment: @SimonBengtsson  `localStorage` is sync function. and it makes chrome app slow.